# Turn off overlay selection on onClick elements on a Touch device

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, touch

I'm building a web app, but after a click on a button, or at least a clickable object, it gets a blue overlay, like a text selection, but on the object. This only happens on touch devices, not on my desktop machine.

It's built with HTML and CSS, so I hope someone knows an appropriate solution for this.

It took me about 20 screenshots, since this overlay is only visible for less than half a second. For those wondering what I actually mean; check this pic. I've tested this on an iPhone (5) and an Android (Nexus 5) and both (although colors differ) appear to have this visual effect. It's either a HTML thing or device-native thing. One thing for sure: It can be set off, since I've never seen this in a regular app. Note: This happens with any clickable item, not just text links.
[image: Screencap]

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that is so that the user can see that the item is clickable. If you care for accessibility you won't do anything about it. On your desktop you get the same when you use the 'tab' button, or click and hold down the mousebutton on a link (a dotted border appears). *If* you want to change it look for the CSS attribute `outline` (for desktop).

Comment: Based upon your comment, you would say that all current mobile developers (native & web app) don't care (less) about accessibility? Since I've never seen such blue (or any color) overlay in any app I've come across. In my opinion, if a user doesn't know it's clickable, you're designing it wrong. At this moment, this overlay seems hideous, but even worse: The whole app is green and the overlay is blue. It's messing the whole style up. Anyway - I'll take a look at `outline` and who knows that might do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gladly found the correct way to adjust this stupid habit of touch devices. It's extremely easy.

You can either turn this off in general (like the code below) or add your own classes/ID's to the selector.

```
a {
...
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
```

Just like that!

Tested on both a few Android and iOS devices, including iPhone 5 & Nexus 5

Answer (score 1):

Try it...

Working http://jsfiddle.net/XbVUR/

```
a{
 -moz-user-select: none; 
 -webkit-user-select: none; 
 -ms-user-select:none; 
 user-select:none;
}

<a href="#" onClick="alert(0)"  unselectable='on' onselectstart='return false;' onmousedown='return false;'>lorem ipsum</a>
```

Comment: Please see the screenshot I've added on the opening post. It's a screenshot of your JSFiddle, where the blue overlay still appears.